# Why can Bijuu be controlled with only three tomoe Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

The Bijuu are legendary creatures created by Hagoromo himself.  Why can they be controlled by simple three tomoe Sharingan, which average Uchiha shinobi obtain?

Comment: Because the Uchiha are Hagoromo's descendents. Also, it is shown that Hagoromo developed Sharingan before he attained the Rinnegan. So basically he's the first Sharingan user. Hence establishing the link between Sharingan, Uchiha and Bijuu.

Comment: thank you for that it's been bothering me for a long time. I didn't really think someone was gonna answer.

Comment: I'll put up a more detailed answer if you want :)

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Reminder for you to convert your comment into an answer :)

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami thank you for the reminders, but I have procrastinated these answers for so long that my priorities changed. I may or may not create an answer for these posts.